# How to prove that the linear transformation of integration from $P_2 to P_3$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given the transformation: 
 $F : P_2 → P_3$ where $F(p(x)) = \int_{0}^{x}p(t) dt$ with standard bases of {$1, x, x^2$} of $P_2$ and  {$1, x, x^2, x^3$} of $P_3$,

how would I go about proving injectivity of this transformation? I presume it has something to do with nullity/ kernel but am unsure how to approach this confidently.

Comment: You can bypass  bases, nullity, kernel. Use the definition of injective.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Not very helpful, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p \in P_2$ and $F(p)=0.$ Then $(\int_{0}^{x}p(t) dt)'=0.$ Hence, by the FTC, $p(x)=0$. Thus $ker(F)= \{0\}.$  Since $F$ is linear, it follows that $F$ is injective.